# Joining two tables where more than X rows in table

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, rows

If we have two tables, say; "users", and "images", how do we select users who have at least X number of images? I believe I need to be using COUNT(), but unsure on the overall syntax...

The "users" table as an *user_id* field, and each image in the "images" row has an "user_id", so the two table tables can be joined using those.

I tried:

```
SELECT users.*, SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM images 
WHERE images.user_id=users.user_id AS num_images 
WHERE num_images>2
```

But no luck - the syntax is wrong, but unsure how you correctly do an inner query, or just join the table where there is at least 2 rows in the images table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_id,COUNT(*)
FROM users u INNER JOIN images i
ON u.user_id=i.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>2;
```

Comment: @HeyThere if the answer helped, you should consider accepting it (clicking on the check-mark outline by the votes for the answer)